# Android Getting ISO Country code

Tags: android

HI I have a requirement that i need to get ISO country code by using Android API by passing longitude and latitude. But not using Google api. Could somebody direct me how to do it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

if you connect to the Internet, you can point to a restful server:
just specify the long and lat and you're set:

`http://ws.geonames.org/countryCode?lat=50&lng=30`